# How to get users from Azure Active Directory into Azure Active Directory B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have a .Net 6 app that needs to be able to be logged into by a list of users that I setup and into my companies Azure Active Directory. Is there a way for B2C to inherit the Azure Active Directory users? I know how to set it up to use just my Azure Active Directory or any Azure Active Directory but I have not yet found out a way to be able to setup Azure Active Directory and B2C authentication from a single C# MVC app. Now keycloak is able to do this but requires I run that and connect to it for authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Federate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) to Azure AD from B2C.

The user then has two choices on the login page. They can log in using either an Azure AD account or the B2C local account.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out thanks rbrayb. The issue is there's currently two ways you can open a B2C. One is by going through the resource group it is located and hitting open b2c tenant. The other is by switching directly into the directory under your profile. If you switch directly into the directory it acts like its own sort of AD and doesn't give you the option to change Identity Providers Company Branding etc.